# Ggplot how to add a breakdown for demographic variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Say I have a database that looks like this:

```
UnnestQ3 <- data.frame(Q3 = c ("mail", "email", "mail", "mail", 
                                "Demonstration", "Videos (Ex: Youtube)",
                                "Podcast", "Podcast", "mail"), Gender = c ("male", "male", "female", "male", "female", "NA", "NA", "Other", "Male")
```

And a bar plot for the total number of responses for each Q3 category made by this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(UnnestQ3, aes(x = Q3)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.75, fill = "blue") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10) +
   geom_text(aes(label = paste0(..count..,"(",round(..count..*100/nrow(UnnestQ3)), "%)")), stat = "count", vjust = 0, colour = "black") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Communication Method") +
  labs(y = "Total Number of Responses (N)")
```

If I wanted to split the bar graph by how many male, female, and others responded per category, how would I go about adding that to the graph? Also, as an aside, if anyone could help me align the counts and percentages better, I'd be hugely appreciative.

Thank you!

Comment: `ggplot(UnnestQ3, aes(x = Q3, fill = Gender)) + geom_bar()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you M.Viking. Adding `fill = Gender` to the aes worked.

```
ggplot(UnnestQ3, aes(x = Q3, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.75) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(..count..," (", 
                              round(..count..*100/nrow(UnnestQ3)), "%)"),
               color = Gender), 
           stat = "count", vjust = 0,  
           position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black", "black", "black", "black"),
                      guide = "none") +
   coord_flip() +
   labs(x = "Communication Method") +
   labs(y = "Total Number of Responses (N)") +
   labs(fill = "Gender") +
   scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

Comment: 1) You have genders `"male"` and `"Male"`. They will be two different genders, with a `..count..` each and showing up in the legend. 2) You are not separating by `color` and even have `scale_color_manual(..., guide = "none")`. Suggestion: in `geom_text`, remove `color` from `aes()` and put `color = "black", show.legend = FALSE` at the end of it. Like this you can simplify the code, `scale_color_manual` won't be needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

## Transforming [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872775/ggplot-how-to-add-a-breakdown-for-demographic-variables/73900596#comment131104488_73900596) to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73900596/8245406) in an answer.

1. The data have genders `"male"` and `"Male"`. Though they are obviously the same, R is case-sensitive and they will be considered two different genders, giving wrong results with a `..count..` each and showing up in the legend as different. Compare the plots below and in the OP's answer, only one of them is right.
2. In `geom_text` colors are separated by `Gender` but then a layer is added, `scale_color_manual` making all text black and removing the color from the legend with `guide = "none"`. Suggestion: in `geom_text`, remove color from `aes()` and put `color = "black", show.legend = FALSE` at the end of it. The code is simplified with one less layer.

I leave the layer `scale_color_manual` in the code but commented out.

```r
UnnestQ3 <- data.frame(Q3 = c("mail", "email", "mail", "mail", 
                               "Demonstration", "Videos (Ex: Youtube)",
                               "Podcast", "Podcast", "mail"), 
                       Gender = c("male", "male", "female", "male", "female",
                                   "NA", "NA", "Other", "Male"))

library(ggplot2)

UnnestQ3 |>
  dplyr::mutate(Gender = ifelse(Gender == "NA", Gender, tolower(Gender))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Q3, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.75) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(..count..," (", 
                               round(..count..*100/nrow(UnnestQ3)), "%)")),
            stat = "count", vjust = 0,  
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            color = "black", show.legend = FALSE) +
  # scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black", "black", "black", "black"),
  #                    guide = "none") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Communication Method") +
  labs(y = "Total Number of Responses (N)") +
  labs(fill = "Gender") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Nitpicking

The plot above has all bars text black, making it difficult to read in a darker background. With a little bit of preparation the color of the darker bars can be plotted in white. The corresponding plot code will also need to undo point 2 above, `color = Gender` is back to the `aes()` and `scale_color_manual` is in.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# create a named colors vector `clrs`
clrs <- ifelse(UnnestQ3$Gender == "NA", "NA", tolower(UnnestQ3$Gender))
clrs <- unique(clrs)
clrs <- setNames(ifelse(grepl("male", clrs), "white", "black"), clrs)
# see what `clrs` is now
clrs
#>    male  female      NA   other 
#> "white" "white" "black" "black"

UnnestQ3 |>
  dplyr::mutate(Gender = ifelse(Gender == "NA", Gender, tolower(Gender))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Q3, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.75) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(..count..," (", 
                               round(..count..*100/nrow(UnnestQ3)), "%)"),
                color = Gender),
            stat = "count", vjust = 0,  
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = clrs, guide = "none") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Communication Method") +
  labs(y = "Total Number of Responses (N)") +
  labs(fill = "Gender") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>